# How should hyphenated LinkedIn People profile fields be handled in PHP?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm basing my code on the sample PHP code LinkedIn makes available at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples.

The differences between their code and mine are few.

The sample code just requests two profile fields:

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)');
```

I wanted a lot more, so I requested all these profile fields as defined at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields:

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,headline,industry,specialties,summary,positions,public-profile-url,email-address,interests,publications,languages,skills,certifications,educations,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,honors-awards)');
```

The request is successful and profile fields are returned and I can print most of them to display. But the fields which are hyphenated, such as `public-profile-url` don't seem to be returning usable data. I must be doing something wrong, because it can't be a coincidence that **all** the hyphenated profile field are empty.

After the successful return I tried using print statements to show the results for each field:

```
print "<br />headline: $user->headline ";
print "<br />industry: $user->industry ";
print "<br /><br />public-profile-url: " . $user->{'public-profile-url'};
print "<br /><br />email-address: " . $user->{'email-address'};
```

etc.

This works for all the fields that were simple strings. For some I needed to use print_r because they were objects.

But I don't get any data at all for the hyphenated fields.

If I try print_r:

```
print_r($user->{'public-profile-url'});
```

the result is blank.

If I try var_dump:

```
var_dump($user->{'public-profile-url'});
```

the result is NULL.

This is the same for **all** the hyphenated profile fields I tried:

public-profile-url
email-address
num-recommenders
date-of-birth
honors-awards

It seems to be too much of a coincidence that just the hyphenated profile fields would all be NULL, so I think I must be doing something else wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

doug

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r($user)`?

Comment: The print_r($user) suggestion was an excellent idea! It revealed that LinkedIn was returning public-profile-url as publicProfileUrl, email-address as emailAddress and num-recommenders as numRecommenders. So I can see those values now if I use those property names! LinkedIn does not appear to return anything at all for date-of-birth or honors-awards though. I wonder where they are, though those are less important. Anyway, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `print_r($user);` you should see to what `public-profile-url` and others are mapped to.

Comment: Thanks again. I managed to get to sleep before 3 am with that.

Answer (score 4):

Your method will work, but to be sure... assign the field to a variable first, then use the variable for the reference.

```
<?php
    $field = 'public-profile-url';

    echo $user->$field; // works

    echo $user->{'public-profile-url'}; // works also
?>
```

If they are coming back as NULL, then they must be NULL

Comment: The answer was actually to be found in AlexV's comment above. LinkedIn was returning the property names with different spelling than was used in the call request. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem. Spelling definitely counts!

Comment: Is there a reason why it's better to assign the field to a variable first and then use the variable for reference rather than the bracketed-quoted format?

Comment: @Doug, it's not necessarily better, i was just demonstrating both ways it can be done and stating that if it was returning NULL that it was NULL since it was correct.

Comment: Also note that there are some subtle differences between the way field identifiers are represented in the default XML output vs. JSON.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn returns always camel case fields, with a lower case first letter, also known as camelBack notation. So you'll have `publicProfileUrl`, etc. Remember instead, when you require them, to use, for every field, the notation `first-name,last-name`: compound words separated by comma. Don't use any space before or after the comma.